# Elasticsearch with grouped query_string

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-php

```
{
   "query":
   {
      "query_string" :
      {
         "query" : "((name:the_search_phrase) OR (keywords:the_search_phrase)) AND (city:Sydney, Australia)"
      }
   }
}
```

New to elasticsearch. Building the JSON as per the documentation here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html

The query runs, however, results with city other that `Sydney, Australia` are returned too. Why the AND part is not working?

I want the search phrase to match against either or both name, keywords but the city should be strictly Sydney.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is a full text query. `city:Sydney, Australia` seems to be a filter query. Like a WHERE clause in a SQL. You are better off using a filter query for that.

Look at the [boolean query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) for examples,

Something like this perhaps,

```
    {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "the_search_term",
            "fields": [
              "name",
              "keywords"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "match": {
            "city": "Sydney, Australia"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `{
            "query":
            {
                "bool" :
                {
                    "should": [                   
                        {"match" : {"name" : "The search Phrase"}},
                        {"match" : {"keywords" : "The search Phrase"}}                    
                    ],
                    "filter" :
                    {
                        "term" : { "city" : "Melbourne, Australia" }  
                    }
                }
            }
        }` I rewrote as this, but no results for whatever **search phrase** and **city**.

Comment: Any mistake in my understanding?

Comment: Updated with an example.

Comment: Thanks for the example. But, this also gets results with city other than Sydney, Australia.

Comment: What do you see when you try `http://your-ES-host:es-port/you-index/_search?q=city:"Sydney, Australia"` Do you see records from other cities as well? Does your "city" field have multiple values in them for same records, like an array?

Comment: Melbourne, Australia is also returned. But when I filter with other parameters, where it does not have common phrases among it, the results are fine.

Example: `type:website`, `type:app` filter results fine.

Please note filter for `Chennai, India` also shows other cities from India, but not from Australia. I think, instead of exact match ES is matching phrases. I tried replacing `match` with `term`, but no results are returned for whatever city entered.

Comment: What does the result of this query look like? Does it show Sydney and Australia in different buckets?

`GET /your-index/_search?size=0
{
    "aggs" : {
        "city" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "city" } 
        }
    }
}`